# How to use an existing result from regexp to filter again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d52bt76e/2/

JavaScript:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=the_time]').change(function () {
  var vResultCount = 0;
  var value = $(this).val();
  var exp = new RegExp('^' + value.toLowerCase(), 'i');
  if (value.toLowerCase() != "any") {
    $(".div1").each(function () {
      if ($(this).css("display") != "none") {
        var isMatch = exp.test($('.leftdv', this).text().toLowerCase().substr($('.leftdv', this).text().length - 2));
        $(this).toggle(isMatch);
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    $(".div1").each(function () {
      $(this).css("display", "");
    });
  }
});

$('input[type=radio][name=the_place]').change(function () {
  var vResultCount = 0;
  var value = $(this).val();
  var exp = new RegExp('^' + value.toLowerCase(), 'i');
  if (value.toLowerCase() != "any") {
    $(".div1").each(function () {
      if ($(this).css("display") != "none") {
        var isMatch = exp.test($('.rightdv', this).text().toLowerCase());
        $(this).toggle(isMatch);
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    $(".div1").each(function () {
      $(this).css("display", "");
    });
  }
});
```

If I first filter by time, and then by place, the time resets. If I first filter by place and then by time, the place resets.

How can I modify so the radio button list is updated (hide the options not application temporarily) based on the regexp and also allow both filters (possibly more radio button groups later on) to work simultaneously.

For example, if I first choose AM, the place radio button should hide `Orlando` radio button and then if I select Miami, it should only display the `0610AM, Miami` option and hide the rest.

**UPDATE:** I was able to do as I wanted by checking to see which `div1`is not set to `display: none` but now my issue is, if I select All from place but keep AM for time, it shows all 4 option instead of the two that has AM. Can I get some help with that please. I update my Fiddle and my script.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The fiddle shows a sample and minimal example.

Comment: 35 lines is minimal?

Comment: I am not sure how minimal i can go... :/

Comment: Guys I can't understand why you should downvote this question. He provided: a jsfiddle sample, explained the problem very well, posted the code and his question is exactly how to have a different approach and how to fix the current bug. 
In the code there is no more than everything that is needed in order to have the two radio groups and a search filtered by them. Upvoted back.

Comment: Thank you @quirimmo

Comment: @alexanderbird How is 35 lines a staggering amount? And why does line number matter if any less lines would make it incomplete?

Comment: I appreciate that it's fully reproducible, and that the desired behavior has been clearly described. What I'm getting at is that it doesn't seem like the principles of [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) have been followed here. It seems that Si8 should have some idea of where in the 35 lines things are going wrong - otherwise it feels like a debugging help question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten the solution, and I'll explain at the end.

```
function filterResults () {
  var timeValue = $('input[type=radio][name=the_time]:checked').val().toLowerCase();
  var timeRegex = new RegExp(timeValue + '$', 'i');
  var placeValue = $('input[type=radio][name=the_place]:checked').val().toLowerCase();
  var placeRegex = new RegExp('^' + placeValue, 'i');

  $('.div1').each(function () {
    var $div = $(this);
    var divTime = $div.find('.leftdv').html();
    var divPlace = $div.find('.rightdv').html();
    $div.toggle(
      (timeValue === 'all' || timeRegex.test(divTime)) &&
      (placeValue === 'any' || placeRegex.test(divPlace))
    );
  });
}

$('input[type=radio][name=the_time]').change(filterResults);
$('input[type=radio][name=the_place]').change(filterResults);
```

- Since there is a lot of code duplication, I've moved the function into one single function which both change-handlers will delegate to.
- This function will apply both filters to each div.
- There was a bug with the *time* regex. The possible values look like `0630PM` but your regex looked like `/^pm/i` which will **never** match. I've changed the regex to `/pm$/i`.
- Don't use `.css('display', 'none')`. jQuery already has builtin methods `hide`, `show`, and `toggle` which is a shortcut to the display:none/block. I've used `toggle` since it accepts a boolean value.

---

Note for possible improvement: Set the "any/all" values to empty strings. `<input value="">`. Then you can remove the "any/all" magic strings altogether. The regex `/^/` and `/$/` will match all results anyway. No need for the extra check.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation... I created the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d52bt76e/6/

Comment: Thanks for creating the jsfiddle for this answer. It looks like you've received some other more complicated answers. Please accept the answer which you feel is more complete, clean, and maintainable.

Comment: @Si8 That's of course the one to be accepted in my opinion! 
I didn't know that toggle accepts expressions too. Thanks Joe :) 
p.s. and I am the "owner" of one the "other more complicated answers". So the maximum of the fair play :)

Comment: yeah that's one of the most beautiful things of SO. I started to use that as "user" (and not only as "reader when needed") one month ago, and in one month I learned a lot of stuffs.

Comment: The simplest one will get my accept check... Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I refactored a bit your sample. You can improve the code of all the first variables just keeping the variables that you really need and maybe you can improve jQuerty code too and a lot of other things too :D

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=the_time]').change(filterResults);
$('input[type=radio][name=the_place]').change(filterResults);

function filterResults() {
 var timeValue = $('input[type=radio][name=the_time]:checked').val();
 var placeValue = $('input[type=radio][name=the_place]:checked').val();
  var timeExp = new RegExp(timeValue.toLowerCase() + '$', 'i');
  var placeExp = new RegExp('^' + placeValue.toLowerCase(), 'i');
  var matchTime = false;
  var matchPlace = false;
  $(".div1").each(function () {
    matchTime = timeValue.toLowerCase() == "any" ? 
      true : 
     timeExp.test($('.leftdv', this).text().toLowerCase());
    matchPlace = placeValue.toLowerCase() == "all" ? 
      true : 
     placeExp.test($('.rightdv', this).text().toLowerCase());
    $(this).toggle(matchTime && matchPlace);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="the_time" value="any" checked="checked">Any <input type="radio" name="the_time" value="am">AM <input type="radio" name="the_time" value="pm">PM
<br />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="the_place" value="all" checked="checked">All <input type="radio" name="the_place" value="Orange County">Orange County <input type="radio" name="the_place" value="Miami">Miami <input type="radio" name="the_place" value="Orlando">Orlando
<br />
<br />
<div class="checkdv">
 <div class="div1">
  <div class="leftdv">0500AM</div>
  <div class="rightdv">Orange county</div>
 </div>
 <div class="div1">
  <div class="leftdv">0610AM</div>
  <div class="rightdv">Miami</div>
 </div>
 <div class="div1">
  <div class="leftdv">0700PM</div>
  <div class="rightdv">Miami</div>
 </div>
 <div class="div1">
  <div class="leftdv">0900PM</div>
  <div class="rightdv">Orlando</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d52bt76e/10/

Comment: This is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your code to track the time and place variables independently. You can see a fiddle of this solution https://jsfiddle.net/d52bt76e/5/

```
// Track time and place seperately

var time = "any";
var place = "any";

$('input[type=radio][name=the_time]').change(function() {
  var vResultCount = 0;
  var value = $(this).val();
  var exp = new RegExp('^' + value.toLowerCase(), 'i');
  // If the value changes we need to check the filter on place as well
  var placeExp = new RegExp('^' + place.toLowerCase(), 'i');
  // no dupe variables
  var isMatch;
  time = value.toLowerCase();

  if (value.toLowerCase() != "any") {
    $(".div1").each(function() {
      isMatch = exp.test($('.leftdv', this).text().toLowerCase().substr($('.leftdv', this).text().length - 2));
      if(place != "any") {
        isMatch = isMatch && placeExp.test($('.rightdv', this).text().toLowerCase());
      }
      $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });
  } else {
    $(".div1").each(function() {
      // we still need to filter on place when not filtering on time
      isMatch = place === 'any' ? true : placeExp.test($('.rightdv', this).text().toLowerCase());

      $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });
  }
});

$('input[type=radio][name=the_place]').change(function() {
  var vResultCount = 0;
  var value = $(this).val();
  place = value.toLowerCase();
  var exp = new RegExp('^' + value.toLowerCase(), 'i');
  var timeExp = new RegExp('^' + time.toLowerCase(), 'i');
  // don't redeclare vars
  var isMatch;
  if (value.toLowerCase() != "any") {
    $(".div1").each(function() {
      isMatch = exp.test($('.rightdv', this).text().toLowerCase());
      if(time != "any") {
        isMatch = isMatch && timeExp.test($('.leftdv', this).text().toLowerCase().substr($('.leftdv', this).text().length - 2));
      }
      $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });
  } else {
    $(".div1").each(function() {
    // We still need to filter on time even when not filtering on place
    isMatch = time === "any" ? true : timeExp.test($('.leftdv', this).text().toLowerCase().substr($('.leftdv', this).text().length - 2));
      $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });
  }
});
```

The key here is that any time one option changes, you need to track the display value of the other. The easiest way to do that is with two separate variables independent of your change function. Here they are globals, but you could accomplish the same with a closure, or some other idiom.

The crucial changes are these

```
  if(place != "any") {
    isMatch = isMatch && placeExp.test($('.rightdv', this).text().toLowerCase());
  }
if(time != "any") {
    isMatch = isMatch && timeExp.test($('.leftdv', this).text().toLowerCase().substr($('.leftdv', this).text().length - 2));
}
```

And these

```
else {
    $(".div1").each(function() {
      // we still need to filter on place when not filtering on time
      isMatch = place === 'any' ? true : placeExp.test($('.rightdv', this).text().toLowerCase());

      $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    }

else {
    $(".div1").each(function() {
    // We still need to filter on time even when not filtering on place
    isMatch = time === "any" ? true : timeExp.test($('.leftdv', this).text().toLowerCase().substr($('.leftdv', this).text().length - 2));
      $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    }
```

In each case what we are doing is the same, checking the value of the other option and making sure to filter on both items.